# The best way for calculated fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, calculated-field

I'm starting to create my first web application in Django. I'm dealing with backEnd part first. In my data structure I need to calculate some fields like average budget of employee's salary for each model object (company, department ..).

I found some ways to calculate and display calculated field in API.

1. Add a property into model and override querySet for better performance.
2. Calculate and add extra field in serializers and display it for API.
3. Use build-in computedfields.models

I can not decide which way is best for calculating fields, what are pros and cons of each way.

Thanks for some advice.

Comment: I use #1 a lot.

Comment: SerializerMethodField method in serializer is what you need. I use property to concat fields whose values are almost constant.

Comment: I would create a model manager and override the get_queryset method specific to the requirement. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/

Comment: Override the model manager. Create your annotations and get this values on serializers.